# Последовательный вывод из массива

Tags: функции, javascript

имеем массив[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0];как вывести значения не рандомно ,а по порядку,переделав эту функцию

```
var tempnumbers={}, tmp='';
while(regLet.test(testnumbers)){
    tmp=letters[Math.floor(Math.random()*(letters.length))];
    if(tempnum[tmp]!=true){
        tempnum[tmp]=true;
    testnum=testnum.replace(regLet, tmp);
```

Чет я итератор не могу сюда прикрутить,помогите плиз.

Comment: да вроде где то так.если у меня количество цифр разное я могу прописать допустим newId=x*getId?что бы понятнее сегодня я буду выводить 11,12,13,а завтра 111,112,113?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

странная какая-то у вас функция. если я вас правильно понял, то это проще простого http://jsfiddle.net/L9m9e/

Comment: @mountpoint, с поправкой на то, что яваскрипт *особенный*: http://jsfiddle.net/L9m9e/1/

Comment: @Fike, так точно. правильно подметили) я уже туплю. пора спать. всем спокойной ночи

Comment: спасибо за варианты.Это типа спросили на какой улице живеш,ответил-в России.Суть вопроса-можно ли без переделки всей функции вместо tmp=letters[Math.floor(Math.random()*(letters.length))];вставить функцию итератора?то биш tmp=newArray for(key in newArr)и т.д7

Comment: @kot197676 a) вот это должно быть в вопросе, потому что решение по порядку все выводит, б) приведенный код невалиден и в) я вообще не могу понять что он делает и какой результат должен быть на выходе.

Comment: ммм на выходе вместо 4,6,9,1 должно быть 1,2,3,4.

Comment: выдает строку значений допустим 4691 следующее 5768 то есть случайных,а я хочу добиться от него 1234,1235,1236и т.д

Comment: @kot197676, твою м..ь, почему Вы это не написали сначала???? Why????!!!!!!!!

Comment: ммм не рандомно а по порядку это не смысл того что я расписал выше?

Comment: ```
getId = (function(){
    var id = 0;
    return function() {
        return ++id;
    };
})();
var id = getId(); // 1
var id = getId(); // 2
var id = getId(); // 3
```